# Android Studio: How to disconnect adb logcat after program is stopped

Tags: android-studio, adb

I am using Android Studio (v1.2.2).  After I run a few times, I want to disconnect from the adb/logcat output without having to completely restart Android Studio.  I need to be able to disconnect because multiple people are using these devices.

If I click on the 'X' (terminate program) in the Run menu, then it stops the program, but the logcat output keeps chugging away and the adb ports are held open by Studio.  How can I close this connection?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to use logcat and keep trace of what happend is to use command line. (I suppose `adb` is your path, if not add the platform-tools directory to your path).

In terminal `adb logcat` give you the logs as Android Studio. When you're done with your app and want the logs to stop interrupt the commnd by typing ctrl + C.

If you want to save the log to a file, use `adb logcat > your_file.txt` to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: This is a great replacement, but it doesn't stop the logcat from running in Studio.  How do I get Studio to *stop* doing the logcat?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know a clean way to do that. You can try `adb disconnect <your_device>` to disconnect adb from your device. This should stop the logcat. But you will not be connected to your device anymore, so to be able to run an app from AS you will need to reconnect to your device with `adb connect <your_device>`.

Comment: I'm confused - where am I supposed to try `adb disconnect`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Probably because I'm using ssh port forwarding to access adb on another machine.  And that means the port forwarding can't quit without killing Android Studio, which seems ridiculous.